# Bootstrap fileinput plugin, icons not showing, how to fix that?

Tags: jquery, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIB9D.png)
I used bootstrap fileinput plugin in my demo, now I can upload Multipartfiles to controller then store then in database, but icons are missing.

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${contextPath}/js/fileinput.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${contextPath}/js/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="${contextPath}/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#fileinput1").fileinput({
            uploadUrl : '${contextPath}/user/uploadnotes2',
            showPreview : false,
            maxFilePreviewSize : 30720,
            maxFileCount : 1,
            allowedFileExtensions : [ "rar", "zip", "7z", "jpg", "png", "bmp" ]
        });
        $("#fileinput2").fileinput({
            uploadUrl : '${contextPath}/user/addsample2',
            maxFileCount : 1,
            allowedFileTypes : [ "image" ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I googled but found no solution yet. Am i missing some .css files? Last time I used summernote the icons int it are missing too, but I imported font-awesome.min.css to fix that. This time in fileinput part, it didn't work.

I am not familiar with front-end skills, please help me. Thank you all.

Comment: add your code and remove the images before you get downvoted

Comment: Share a url where you have this implemented online.

Answer (score 0):

Still thank the two guys who posted comments. I fixed this by putting all the bootstrap package in my web project (in webapp) . Then import bootstrap.min.css using more detailed path.

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${contextPath}/js/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```